# How to integrate 1С with Django?

Tags: django, 1c

There is an online store built on Django. How do I set up an exchange of data on products between Django and 1C? I have checked some documentation on the CommerceML format, but it is still unclear how to set it up on the 1C side. As far as I understand, all uploads are configured quite simply. You just need to register the URL of the handler. And then everything happens automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 1с provides an algorithm for interacting with the upload script by which files of product offers are uploaded to the server.
Therefore, you can configure data exchange with external sources and sites, for this in your solution, go to the menu item Administration - Data Exchange and check the box "Data exchange with sites" where you specify the directories and documents involved in the exchange.  After downloading the XML files, you just need to process them on the server side. There is information on the developer's forum https://1c-dn.com/forum/forum11/topic2308/ with the methods of exchange settings and API  , see if one of the methods suggested there will help you. They also have a blog article about different ways of integration https://1c-dn.com/blog/work-with-http-services-in-1c-part-1-get-method/